# How can I dispatch a determined store state?

Tags: rxjs, angular7

I have implemented the management to have more tables within my component, but when I load the data it does so with all the tables having the store.

If I wanted to discriminate my tables by reloading the data only of a specific table in my store effects how can I do?

Comment: Assume that you have 5 tables in your view then you should maintain 5 separate data for those tables in the store. Updating the respective data [i.e. specific table data] in the store will make to refresh only that table for which data in the store is updated.

Comment: Yes, i have to separate data tables. In my situation if i dispatch one table 
the others are also updated.

Comment: This question seems a bit confusing to me. Would you clarify your position and the restate the problem? Maybe show a bit of code to better illustrate the problem?

Comment: if i have 3 grid in only one component and i dispatch reload store action, all of my grids are reloaded. How can i focus just one grid and realod only one ?